# Connection string for parameterized Linked Services - Azure SQL / Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have a requirement where in I need to parameterize my Azure SQL/Azure Synapse linked service using 2 parameters 'DBServer' and 'DBName'. I configured my collaboration branch as below and everything works as expected in my Synapse workspace.

[image]

Even the linked service ARM template shows the connection string values as expected.

[image]

However when I publish the code (*using the publish button in Synapse workspace*), the code in the Synapse Live mode does not contain these parameters defined. Please see the snippet below.

[image]

Even the code in the TemplateParameter file of the publish branch is blank.

[image]

I tried removing the parameters and put in the actual values for Server and DBName, it still shows no values in the publish branch/Live mode. While I understand that the git mode does not store secrets, this case of mine does not have any secrets and I am authenticating via Managed Identity.
Is there a solution to deal with this scenario? I would not prefer to store the connection string in KeyVault and refer it back in the linked service as it does not make the solution completely dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I created Azure sql database and created synapse pool in Azure portal. I created SQL linked service in synapse pool with managed identity authentication.
to authenticate with managed identity, I created user in SQL database with synapse pool name using below query

```
create  user [SynapsePoolName] from  external  provider;

ALTER  ROLE db_owner ADD  MEMBER [SynapsePoolName];
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Linked service:

[image]

I published the Linked Service with publish button.
Image for reference:

[image]

It published successfully.

[image]

When I open the linked service after publish, I am getting the parameters.

Image for reference:

[image]

I got the parameters in template also.

Image for reference:

[image]

It worked in my machine kindly check from your side.